# adding a sidemenu page after login page (blank tab)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new in Ionic and just started ionic 2-3 days back.

I have created a project, removed home page and added a new page called login.

First removed the default home page and added login page, then added two input fields, one button which is binded with post call to server to authenticate user.

Login page is coming from `<router-outlet>` as the application starts.

If the login is successful. I want to route in a page where I have navigation bar i.e. `<ion-menu>`. For example I've created 3 pages in the same directory where login is.

SideMenu Page.
Dashboard Page.
Request Page.

All have their own template, css file, page file and service file.

I want to configure my side-menu page in such a way that it should show dashboard page as default, have dashboard and request page in menu list and side-menu should only display navigation mechanism.

In my case I'm using Ionic 4 so lazy loading is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your authenticated user saved on storage, you can take it, from storage and display or not the side menu. Something like this:

```
<side-menu *ngIf="authUser"></side-menu>
```

Comment: Maybe my question didn't express correctly because of english but I want to create a page with side-menu implementation which will come up after login.